# Using Helicon ISAPI Rewrite v3 Lite on IIS6

Tags: iis-6, isapi-rewrite, isapi-redirect

Could anyone help me on how to configure IIS 6 to use ISAPI Rewrite v3 Lite. I've installed it already and I've tried using sample rewriting withe Host being my website and I've also added the .dll to the ISAPI Filter but my site won't redirect right.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to adjust in IIS. You install ISAPI_Rewrite 3, use ISAPI_Rewrite Manager to edit you httpd.conf (.htaccess files are disabled in LITE version).

What rules do you use? It's usually '/' in front of the pattern that screws everything.